# Async await now working in Nuxt component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two functions,
One function converts images from whatever format to canvas, then to WEBP image format.
The other function receives the image and `console.log` the image.

The problem is that when I log the result of the image in the `saveToBackend` function, I get a result of undefined, but when I `console.log` the converted image in the `convertImage` function, I get the image. Please how can i solve the issue?

Below are the functions in my NUXT app

```
        convertImage(file) {
            // convert image
            let src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            let userImage = new Image();
            userImage.src = src

            userImage.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = userImage.width;
                canvas.height = userImage.height;
                ctx.drawImage(userImage, 0, 0);

                let webpImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
                console.log(webpImage); // with this i get the image in the console
                return webpImage
            }
        },
        async saveToBackend(file, result) {
            // convert images to webp
            let webpFile = await this.convertImage(file)
            console.log(webpFile); // with this i get undefined in the console
        }
```

Comment: `convertImage` is neither `async` nor returns a promise, so `await`ing it will do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return `webpImage` from inside the onload callback. It simply will not wait for `onload` to execute. You can instead create a `Promise` that resolves the value of `webpImage` when `onload` completes:

```
convertImage(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // convert image
    let src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let userImage = new Image();
    userImage.src = src;

    userImage.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = userImage.width;
      canvas.height = userImage.height;
      ctx.drawImage(userImage, 0, 0);

      let webpImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
      console.log(webpImage); // with this i get the image in the console
      // resolve promise so that saveToBackend can await it
      return resolve(webpImage);
    };
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Bro thank you for your answer, I have learned something new from it. I will mark it as correct.